# Why does display flex allow margin:auto 0; to center the content?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain the logic behind this code?

I want to know why making the `div#a1` flex allows to center `div#a2` by `margin:auto 0;` which doesn't work without making `div#a1` flex.

```css
#a1{
  display:flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border:3px solid black;
}

#a2{
    height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border:3px solid red;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id=a1>
     <div id="a2">
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/

Comment: it was defined to work that way

Answer (score -1):

change the #a2 to this

```
#a2{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border:3px solid red;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Answers which explain the code given are downvoted less often than those which just show code without explanation.

Comment: You didn't answer the question ;)

Comment: Because you mention the margin of a2 as 0 so it will start from the left,
The difference between the red and the black one is 50px diveded by 2 =25px

Comment: Im not a good as that in english hope that this helped you :)